# JavaFX Remove ToolBar Gradient

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, javafx

How can I remove the gradient from the toolbar in JavaFX.

This is what I've tried so far, but the background color doesn't show at all and the toolbar remains in its regular state.

```
.toolbar{
    -fx-font-family: "Lato-Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-color: #fff;
    -fx-background: #3498db;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: -fx-background **-color**: #3498db;

If that doesnt work seem like you have problem with connecting it with your css file.

Try using your `-fx-background-color: #3498db;`
with `setStyle("-fx-background-color: #3498db");` method on your ToolBar, see if result changed, then try to debug your application to use your file correctly.(I recommend using SceneBuilder)

The blue area is the toolbar with the specified blue background color (#3498db).

[image: toolbar]

Comment: Tried it with SceneBuilder and it works fine now! Thanks!